# How do I get buttons to do things for gui hangman

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I am new to python and have decided to create a hangman game as a GUI with tkinter. I have stumbled across this problem where I can't get my buttons to do what I want. Specifically, I want them to check if the letter is in the mystery word and print it in the position of the letter in the word if it is. Any tips or suggestions will be helpful.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import Label, Canvas

root = Tk()
root.title("Hangman Project")
c: Canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="white")
c.pack()
height = 400
width = 400
head = c.create_oval(70, 70, 130, 130)
neck = c.create_line(100, 130, 100, 150)
body = c.create_rectangle(70, 150, 130, 220, fill="orange")
arm1 = c.create_line(130, 170, 150, 120)
arm2 = c.create_line(70, 170, 50, 120)
leg1 = c.create_line(110, 220, 145, 275)
leg2 = c.create_line(90, 220, 55, 275)


def gallows():
    c.create_line(width / 40, height / 8, width / 4, height / 8)
    c.create_line(width / 40, height / 8, width / 40, height / 1.6)
    c.create_line(0, height / 1.6, width / 20, height / 1.6)
    c.create_line(width / 40, height / 5, width / 4, height / 8)
    c.create_line(width / 4, height / 8, width / 4, height / 5.7)


line = """Antiquated outdated fashioned Choleric easily angered Diorama 
    model scene Fecund fertile Inebriation drunkenness intoxication Marshal gather 
    together Parity equality Profound meaning Servile overly submissive groveling Usurp 
"""
line.lower()
word_list = list(line.split(" "))
correct_ans = word_list
prize_word = random.choice(word_list)
spaces = " ".join(prize_word)
mystery_word = " ".join("_" * len(prize_word))
y = Label(root, text=mystery_word, font="Times, 30")
y.place(x=190, y=300)


def makebuttons():
    count = 0
    lst = []
    if count <= 27:
        for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
            lst.append(letter)
        for letter in lst:
            Buttons = Button(master=root, text=letter, font="Times, 20")
            Buttons.pack()
            Buttons.place(x=20 * count, y=460)
            count += 1



makebuttons()
gallows()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `command` argument of those buttons are not set, so nothing will happen when they are clicked.

Comment: acw1668 how do I create a command that checks if the letter is in the mystery word and if it is, print it in the position of the letter in the word.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- `line.lower()` will not modify `line`, so use `line = """...""".lower()` instead
- `line.split()` will contain `""` and `"\n"` which need to be filtered out
- redundant code in `makebuttons()`: `if` statement is not necessary and the two `for` loops can be merged into one

Below is a modified version of part of your code with a new function `check_letter()` which will be executed when a letter button is clicked:

```
line = """Antiquated outdated fashioned Choleric easily angered Diorama 
    model scene Fecund fertile Inebriation drunkenness intoxication Marshal gather 
    together Parity equality Profound meaning Servile overly submissive groveling Usurp 
""".lower()
word_list = [x for x in line.split(" ") if x != "" and x != "\n"] # filter out all "" and "\n"
prize_word = list(random.choice(word_list)) # use list instead of string for easy modification
print(prize_word)
mystery_word = ["_"] * len(prize_word) # use list instead of string for easy modification
y = Label(root, text=mystery_word, font=("Times", 30))
y.place(x=190, y=300)

def check_letter(c):
    found = False
    for i, letter in enumerate(prize_word):
        if c == letter:
            prize_word[i] = "-"
            mystery_word[i] = c  # update the guess result
            found = True
    if found:
        y['text'] = mystery_word
    else:
        # do whatever you want if letter is not found
        pass

def makebuttons():
    for i,letter in enumerate("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
        Button(root, text=letter, font=("Times", 14), width=2, command=lambda c=letter: check_letter(c)).place(x=30*i+10, y=460)
```

You need to modify `check_letter()` function to cater two situations:

- when all letters in the mystery word are found
- when the letter is not found in the mystery word

Hope this help.